# How does a light move in a material?

Tags: visible-light

How does a light move in a material?

" aa=  moves in a vacuum --> captured by an atom for 10^(-8) sec  --> vacuum -> captured by an atom --> and so on. "

Is aa= true? you can say something about "10^(-8) sec" capturing time too because i dont know, i might hear about it somewhere long long ago.

Is this why the speed of light is slower than a vacuum?

Answer (score 0):

Light, the classical electromagnetic wave, consists of an enormous number of photons in a quantum mechanical super-positions which build it up.

Photons are quantum mechanical entities. They may interact in three ways:

Elastic scatter, inelastic scatter, absorption in an atom by exciting electrons to higher energy levels.

In a transparent medium all three may happen, but the highest probability is an elastic scattering of each photon with the lattice of the medium, if there is no frequency change; inelastically again with the total lattice of the transparent medium if there is a color change. If the dominant mode is absorption by energy levels in the atoms, then it is no longer a transparent medium. It might be opaque.

The speed of light is slower than in vacuum because the photons do not follow the optical ray path within the medium in [building up the classical light.](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html) They have longer effective paths due to the elastic scatter. They still build up the classical wave but the effective group velocity of light gets smaller.